# Referencing packages from another java project in a jsf project

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat

I'm working on a JSF project. There's another project that has a lot of packages with some functionaly that I'd like to use, but when I add the references of these packages in my jsf project, it stops working. When I remove these references, it works. I've read that you can't reference another project packages in another project with java.  Is it true?

Is there any solution?

Comment: Add some details.  Specifically define what you mean by "add references to these packages in my jsf project".  If the other project produces a jar and you include the jar in the JSF project's classpath, then you can import classes from the other project and use them

Comment: Surely you can. Ultimately, that other project should end up as JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` of the webapp project. The answer depends on tooling used. What tooling are you using? Eclipse?

Comment: What does "stops working" evaluate to? Runtime Exceptions? Compile time errors? Not deploying?

Comment: Ah the famous "it stops working" problem. It's very close to the "it doesn't work" problem. You'll find plenty of questions about this problem here. ;-)

Comment: Add more information about your problem. It's not clearly enough.